# How can I perform a mapkit search for an address or business name outside of local area?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit

I would like to search a map using either an address or a business name/type and have the result(s) displayed with dropped pins.  After much research, I found Google Places API.  Following their [instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches), I'm able to build a URL that will allow me to search for things in a local area.

The problem that I'm having is when I want to search for something outside of the area. Here are some of the parameters.

Required parameters (not a full list)

- location=*longitude,latitude* - The latitude/longitude around which to retrieve Place information. This must be specified as latitude,longitude.
- radius - Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return Place results. The maximum allowed radius is 50,000 meters.

Optional parameter (not a full list)

- keyword  that is used to specify the search term

How can I get results if I search for something out of the area, given the 50,000 meter radius limit?

Thanks.

Comment: why you really want to show results beyond 50 kms? thn what is your limit??

Comment: Either my question wasn't clear or your understanding wasn't. :)  Either way, for whatever reason, you want to look up something that isn't close to the area that is currently displayed.  With my understanding of Google Places API, you can't do that if the place is beyond 50KMs. Maybe Google Places API isn't the right solution for what I need?  Any ideas?  Thanks.